# Ubuntu freezes on Surface Pro 5

Tags: encryption, 18.10, surface, micro-sd

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my new surface pro 2017. To not change anythings on the internal storage, I put Linux on the Samsung micro SD card of 128GB class 10 U3, and to prevent any data leak, I encrypted the whole card. 
Then I installed the surface kernel 4.18.20 and almost all stuff work great except the cameras (but it doesn't matter). 
The only issue that I noticed is that Linux often seems to freeze for a bit.

I think it depends on the storage speed obviously.

But if I install Ubuntu still on the micro SD card without encrypting it, can I solve the problem ?

In that case, it makes sense to encrypt only the home partition ?